# getSelection() bug at 65536

Tags: javascript, html, text

I'm using javascript to retrieve the initial and last character of a selected portion of a text using the function `window.getSelection()`.

I'm working in Google Chrome 70 on Mac.

When the text is long more than 65536 (2^16) I have this issue: if I select a word of, let's say, 10 characters that starts at 65533, the starting point is ok (i.e. 65533) but the ending point correspond to the actual position minus 65536 (65543 - 65536 = 7).

It seems like the browser is dividing the long texts into chunks of 65536 characters (64KB?) and the function `window.getSelection()` works inside of them without knowing the actual position of the selection.

Try the attached snippet if the description is not clear :)

One solution could be to add 65536 to the ending part of the selection when smaller than the starting part, but would work only when across the first and the second chunk of text and only if I select from left to right. I'd need to preserve the number corresponding to the real position of the selected characters to achieve my goal.

Many thanks to all of you who will try to help <3

```js
// A text of 783 characters get repeated untill it reaches 4 times the amount of 65536 characters
// then it is inserted into the div #text-box

let myText = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla imperdiet dignissim finibus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aenean vitae mauris dolor. Pellentesque eu turpis eu magna interdum pretium. Praesent ligula risus, interdum nec nunc vitae, imperdiet commodo nibh. Phasellus ac dolor at magna pretium tincidunt. Pellentesque sagittis finibus mi, at gravida elit pulvinar at. Proin malesuada justo laoreet nisi fermentum tincidunt. Sed tincidunt commodo sapien, quis fermentum velit suscipit volutpat. Ut sit amet ligula convallis, auctor eros a, finibus justo. Curabitur non eros malesuada, dignissim arcu vel, tincidunt augue. Aenean vitae accumsan turpis, id accumsan augue. Ut a massa ac neque interdum tempus.`;
let newText = '';
for (var i = 0; i<335; i++) {
  newText += myText;
}
document.getElementById('text-box').innerHTML = newText;

// grab the selection
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', textSelection);
function textSelection() {
  if (window.getSelection().focusNode.parentElement.id == 'text-box') {
    let currentSelection = window.getSelection().toString();
    let currentSelectionStart = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
    let currentSelectionEnd = window.getSelection().focusOffset;
    document.getElementById('selection').innerHTML = currentSelection;
    document.getElementById('start').innerHTML = currentSelectionStart;
    document.getElementById('end').innerHTML = currentSelectionEnd;
  }
}
```

```css
#info-box {
  background-color: #FEF9E7;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="info-box">
  <h5>Selection starts at <span id="start">.</span></h5>
  <h5>Selection ends at <span id="end">.</span></h5>
  <h5>Text selected: <span id="selection">.</span></h5>
</div>

<div id="text-box">

</div>
```